# add suffix to duplicate fields in one column

Tags: awk, sed

example input file contains rows with tab delimited fields:

```
raw1    aaa    wer
raw2    bbb    dfg
raw3    ccc    fgh
raw4    ccc    etr
raw5    aaa    cbg
raw6    aaa    dfg
```

I need to add suffix `(dupl)` to second column if it's value occurs in 2nd column of any other line too

Expected output for above input is:

```
raw1    aaa(dupl)   wer
raw2    bbb dfg
raw3    ccc(dupl)   fgh
raw4    ccc(dupl)   etr
raw5    aaa(dupl)   cbg
raw6    aaa(dupl)   dfg
```

For now I have following code but it doesn't work efficiently with huge input files:

```
cut -d$'\t' -f2 input|\
sort|\
uniq -c|\
awk '$1>1{print $2}'|\
while read dup;do gawk -F$'\t' -i inplace -va=$dup '$2==a{$2=a"(dupl)"}1' OFS=$'\t' input;done
```

What would be the easier way to achieve the same with single awk or sed command, and without multiple pipes as above?

Answer (score 2):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
raw1    aaa wer
raw2    bbb dfg
raw3    ccc fgh
raw4    ccc etr
raw5    aaa cbg
raw6    aaa dfg
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}FNR==NR{arr[$2]+=1;next}arr[$2]>1{$2=$2 "(dupl)"}{print}' file.txt file.txt
```

gives output

```
raw1    aaa(dupl)   wer
raw2    bbb dfg
raw3    ccc(dupl)   fgh
raw4    ccc(dupl)   etr
raw5    aaa(dupl)   cbg
raw6    aaa(dupl)   dfg
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that tab character (`\t`) is both field separator (`FS`) and output field separator (`OFS`) and I ran `file.txt` twice, first pass is used to build array `arr` so keys are 2nd fields and values numbers of their appearance, then in second pass where there were more than 1 occurrence I add `(dupl)` as suffix to 2nd field, for every line I `print` it.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: @GillesQuenot problem statement claims that *input file contains rows with tab delimited fields*